# How to check if UIView is at coordinates

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a tableView with textFields inside of them, and I have animation that slides the tableView up when the textFieldDidBeginEditing method is called. Here is my code:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.headerView.alpha = 0.2;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.18];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    self.theTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 130, 320, 209);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The problem is that the animation happens whenever one of the cells is tapped, but I only want it to happen the first time a cell is tapped. So I was thinking that I should make an if statement that checks whether the tableView is at the (0, 130) coordinates. Does anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an exact comparison, `CGPointEqualToPoint()` will suffice.  For a broader comparison (checking if the rect of the view contains the given point), `CGRectContainsPoint()` is perfect.

Of course, all of this is a little much.  Subclass your view and keep a flag on it to track whether or not they've been slid up.  Not only does it keep your code more self-contained, but it keeps the logic for the view out of your controller.

Comment: What do you mean by keep a flag on it? I'm pretty new to iOS programming.

Comment: A simple bool will suffice.  Set it to yes when it's been moved, and no when it's been adjusted back into place.  It makes for cleaner if-statements, and subclasses are cheap